# Работа с несколькими репозиториями

Tags: git

Вопрос может и элементарный, но я тут запутался. Итак: Есть репозиторий с определенным шаблоном. Я его клонирую к себе:

```
git clone
```

Теперь мне необходимо переключиться на какой либо репозиторий (например test), и стянуть оттуда файлы в этот же каталог, который я склонировал ранее.

```
git remote add test https://two_repositoty.ru
git pull test master  (по видимому не правильно, git ругается "fatal: отказ слияния несвязанных историй изменений")
```

Далее я в данном каталоге провожу какие то изменения, работы и далее делаю коммиты и работаю только с репозиторием test (второй репозиторий)

Подскажите правильную последовательность действий.

Comment: В одном каталоге один репозиторий. Не должно быть «переключится на другой репозиторий».

Comment: Тогда как правильно работать с двумя репозиториями? Ситуация то такая: Репозиторий с шаблоном - не мой. Я могу оттуда сделать git clone и все. Дальше мне нужно со своего репозитория подтянуть некоторые файлы, слить это все в один проект и работать с ним у себя.

Comment: Клонируйте шаблоны в папку `templates`, свой проект - в папку `test`, затем руками перенесите нужные вам файлы из папки `templates` в `test` и работайте с ними там. Если вы не собираетесь модифицировать файлы шаблона, то можете сделать вложенный репозиторий templates внутри папки test и ссылаться на шаблон в этой вложенной папке.

Comment: То есть только ручное копирование? Шаблон будет изменяться, на основании его и будет строиться проект, значит по всей видимости вложенный репозиторий - не мой вариант. Спасибо. Если перенесете ваш комментарий в ответ - отмечу его как правильный.

Comment: Если шаблон будет изменяться, но хочется иметь вложенный репо, то надо делать свой форк templates, а изменения пушить в отдельную ветку. Это имеет смысл делать, если вам когда-нибудь в будущем понадобится подтянуть изменения из исходного репо и смержиться с ним.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ну это слишком строго. Если проект большой и есть множество удалённых веток, в которых ведётся часть разработки всего проекта, то их имеет смысл держать в remote у себя.

Comment: @0andriy можно держать несколько апстримов если они по сути клоны одного и того же репозитория. Но обычно нет смысла держать совершенно разнородные репозитории

Comment: Держите два репозитория в одном дереве, ничего постыдного в этом нет. Потом через `git checkout ...` переключайтесь как хотите. Можно с помощью скриптов на регулярной основе "подтягивать" обновления файлов, если они делаются не атомарно (вместе с другми, ненужными вам файлами.